# How to redirect to a translatable page

Tags: uri, redirection, i18n-l10n

I have a bilingual site and I want to redirect to a custom page, which has two language versions, upon form submitting. This may be a pretty basic thing, but I am only starting to learn how to code for Drupal in PHP. This is what I tried:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = t('message-sent-successfully');
```

'message-sent-successfully' is the URL for the English version of the page. It has a different URL for the other language the site is using. In whatever language I submit the form, I get redirected to the above URL, i.e. the url doesn't get translated.

Comment: Using `node/[nid]` instead should solve this problem; the user should be redirected to the proper alias of the node, translated in the currently active language.

Comment: I just tried this and the two translations have two different node ID's which is quite a surprise to me.

Comment: Hm, I might be mistaken - will check it now quickly.

Comment: This works as I mentioned, but you need to have i18n module + globalredirect configured; will post it as an answer as there isn't enough space here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) and enable the Translation Redirect module within.

Install [Globalredirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) and go to `admin/config/system/globalredirect` and check "Language path checking".

You can then take the user to either source or translated node, and Globalredirect will take the user to the page which is in the currently active language.